# iOS multiple entites for one managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, managedobjectcontext

There is a core data model with two entities i my iOS application.

**Entity: Unit / Attributes: unit_name - NSString**

->> Relationship to `Exercise` (`one to many`)

**Entity: Exercise / Attributes: exercise_name - NSString .**

So one `unit` can have many `exercises`.

In my table view controller are all available `exercises` listed.
(So in the first time, i make a fetch request for the `Exercise` entity and the `managedObjectContext` points to this entity.

If i want to save a `"NEW"` `unit` with `exercises` the save function doesn't work.
There is no error at all, but the `unit` table is still empty.

Here is the code for the save function:

```
 Units *newUnit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Units"   inManagedObjectContext:[self.coreDataHelper managedObjectContext]];
    newUnit.unit_name = unitTextField.text;//Attribute
    newUnit.exercises = exerciseSet;//Relationship (NSSet)

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self.coreDataHelper managedObjectContext]save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"There was an error! %@", error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }
```

It seems like the `managedObjectContext` still points to the `Exercise` entity. (Because it was initialized the first time with this entity) the `coreDataHelper` has the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, the `NSManagedObjectContext`, the `NSManagedObjectModel` and some methods to read write and delete.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does you question have a typo, or does your code have "Units" in the insertNewObjectForEntityName method, while you said that your entity is Unit?

Comment: Any entity will be saved that contains the context. Make sure the self.coreDataHelper is not null and that you are passing this to the current controller properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify that everything is connected the way it ought to be, add

```
NSAssert(self.coreDataHelper, @"null coreDataHelper");
NSAssert(self.coreDataHelper.managedObjectContext, @"null MOC");
NSLog(@"available entities: %@", 
    self.coreDataHelper.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName);
```

You ought to see `"Units"` as one of your entities, if you've set everything up correctly.

And then after your insertion of newUnit, verify that it worked:
    NSAssert(newUnit, @"newUnit didn't get inserted");

This smells like a logic error to me, by the way: you're creating a new Units instance every time you save? Are you sure you don't want to use a find-or-create pattern instead?